# Did Griphook survive the events of The Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

In the book version of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, we see Griphook escape with the sword of Gryffindor:

> Hardly aware of the pain from the burns covering his body, and still borne along on the swell of replicating treasure, Harry shoved the cup into his pocket and reached up to retrieve the sword, but Griphook was gone. Sliding from Harry's shoulders the moment he could, he had sprinted for cover amongst the surrounding goblins, brandishing the sword and crying, 'Thieves! Thieves! Help! Thieves!' He vanished into the midst of the advancing crowd, all of whom were holding daggers and who accepted him without question.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.436 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 26, *Gringotts*

Whereas in the film version, he is later shown among the dead at Malfoy Manor, slain by Voldemort in his anger upon hearing that Hufflepuff's cup had been stolen

[image]

I can find no mention of this in the book, nor do I believe anything more is said of Griphook.

So, do we know what happened to Griphook in book canon? Did he survive? I find it hard to see why he would have borne the Sword of Gryffindor to Malfoy Manor as he does in the film.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the book, the quote you've posted is the last reference to Griphook. He's seen running away and is not heard from (or seen, or referred to) again.

There's some conjecture that the "[Goblin Killed by Voldemort](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_goblin_killed_by_Voldemort)" may be Griphook but it doesn't really bear up to scrutiny for a number of good reasons, not least that Harry would have used his name.

Aside from the Deathly Hallows II film, wherein his death is depicted in vivid detail, there's really no good reason to assume that he did anything other than escape and continue to live a long and <s>happy</s> grumpy life.

Comment: Probably very grumpy, since the Sword would have disappeared from his possession, but good answer! :)

Comment: The look on his face when the Sword of Gryffindor de-materialised must have been [truly epic](https://media.giphy.com/media/OAthVeXHlBnFK/giphy.gif)