# Can Griphook plea against Gryffindor's magic to have it removed?

Tags: harry-potter

Griphook made a deal to acquire Gryffindor's sword from Harry but he eventually just took it from him while breaking into Gringotts. But, later when Neville pulled out Gryffindor's sword from the sorting hat (to kill Nagini), I believe it vanished from the vault of Griphook and didn't return.

While wizards don't agree with the goblins' way of treating wealth (goblins believe that a goblin-made object should be returned to the maker once the owner dies, instead of passing it down to generations), Griphook did have rights to the sword, via Harry (who was given the sword by Dumbledore through his [Dumbledore's] will).

Can Griphook plea in court to have Gryffindor's magic removed from the sword (whether it can be removed or not is another issue)?

Comment: Griphook didn't "win" the sword from Harry, because Harry never owned it, because Dumbledore didn't have the right to give it to harry through a will. As to your question, goblins and wizards seem to have a difference of opinions on some subjects __that will not be resolved__. He can plea, but eh.

Comment: to answer the direct question, Griphook can plea for anything on account of him being dead.

Comment: @Skooba, only in the movie version, I believe?  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143568/did-griphook-survive-the-events-of-the-deathly-hallows